# How to find center coordinate of UINavigationBar item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I need to show some popover and for that I need position of right navigation bar button. currently I used

```
x = self.view.frame.width - 30
y = self.view.frame.origin.y + 60
```

But I think It's not a good way, Because iPad screen in landscape view the view.frame.origin.y is a bit diff to iPhone in the same situation.

Comment: use this code self.yourView.center = self.view.center;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this

```
if let rightBarButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem {
    if rightBarButton.valueForKey("view") != nil {
            // here you can access the frame like this buttonView.frame
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can give you correct location converted to super view, updated from Rajat answer:

```
if let rightBarButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem {
        if let buttonView = rightBarButton.valueForKey("view") {
            let frame = self.navigationController?.view.convertRect(buttonView.frame, toView: self.view)
            print("frame \(frame)") //(330.5, 6.0, 40.0, 30.0)
        }
}
```

Comment: 'UIBarButtonItem' has not member 'view'

Comment: This is swift 2, maybe it's removed in swift 3, you can try combine with the answer from Rajat to get the frame and use it in this

Comment: oh yes, i forgot that i have an UIView extension for this :/ the above answer can provide the view